# Segmentation fault when compiling Darknet for GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nvcc, darknet

I want to compile the Darknet framework for machine learning on my PC with GPU support. However I call make I will get a segmentation fault:

```
nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/convolutional_kernels.cu -o obj/convolutional_kernels.o
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Makefile:92: recipe for target 'obj/convolutional_kernels.o' failed
make: *** [obj/convolutional_kernels.o] Error 139
```

*nvidia-smi* gives me following information:

```
NVIDIA-SMI 418.87.01    Driver Version: 418.87.01    CUDA Version: 10.1
```

When I do *nvcc --version* I get:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

The CUDA Version 10.1 is not the same as the Verions 9.1 of the Cuda compilation tools. Could this be the problem? NVCC is installed via *apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit*

Comment: The nvidia-smi version shown has nothing whatsoever to do with what version of the CUDA toolkit you have installed. It only shows what the installed driver supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. After installing cuda the actual binary of nvcc is at /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc. Creating a symbolic link in /usr/bin/ to this binary solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just gonna post my solution here because I figured out the actual reason for this. So the reason this happens is because it's running a different binary than the actual one darknet wants to run. At least for me, `which nvcc` gave me `/usr/bin/nvcc`. The actual `nvcc` you want is located in `/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin` (version number might be different obviously). So all you need to do is *prepend* (important!) that directory to your PATH variable.

`export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}} >> ~/.bashrc`

Source:https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions

I recommend you follow the link because there are a couple more mandatory post-installation steps that I also did not follow.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to edit the Makefile and set the correct nvcc.
In my case:
line 24 replace

```
NVCC=nvcc
```

to

```
NVCC=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/nvcc
```

Note that the cuda version may vary.